# Download subset of file from s3 using Boto3

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

Using boto, I was able to download just a subset of a file from Amazon s3. Given an s3 key, I specified the start and stop bytes and passed them into the `get_contents_as_string` call.

```
# Define bytes to focus on
headers={'Range' : 'bytes={}-{}'.format(start_byte, stop_byte)}
resp = key.get_contents_as_string(headers=headers)
```

Is there a way to accomplish the same task in boto3?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use the same `Range` parameter in [`get_object()`](https://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.get_object) method:

```
s3 = boto3.client('s3')
resp = s3.get_object(Bucket='bucket', Range='bytes={}-{}'.format(start_byte, stop_byte))
content = resp['Body']
```