# how to read the first row of data from a csv file in S3 without reading the whole file using aws lambda?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, iteration, response, read.csv

I m trying to create an AWS lambda function that only reads the first row of data from a big csv file stored in an S3 bucket.
This function will be triggered many times and if we are going to read the whole csv (500+Mb) it will cost so much, I need to get the first row of data only.
And I found that we can do that with `iter_lines().__next__()`  then decode it
So I tried the following code:

```
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    # Set the S3 bucket and CSV file path
    bucket_name = "bucket"
    file_name = "path"
    
    # Get the CSV file from S3
    response = s3.get_object(Bucket=bucket_name, Key=file_name)
    
    
    #First line used to give the header (feature names)
    # Create a StreamingBody object that reads only the first line
    first_line_stream = response['Body'].iter_lines().__next__()
    # Convert the first line to a string
    first_line = first_line_stream.decode('utf-8')
    # Use the CSV module to parse the first line
    csv_reader = csv.reader([first_line])
    first_row = next(csv_reader)
   
    #Second line
    # Second line (we just do next twice)
    second_line_stream = response['Body'].iter_lines().__next__()
    # Convert the second line to a string
    second_line = second_line_stream.decode('utf-8')
    # Use the CSV module to parse the second line
    csv_reader = csv.reader([second_line])
    second_row = next(csv_reader)
    
    print(first_row, '\n', second_row)
    print('Header len: ',len(first_row) ,' len second:',len(second_row))
```

But I the second line (which is the first data row) is not correct
Here are the results:

```
['20 columns'] 
['53125', '0', '0', '0', '1678849176273']
Header len:  20  len second: 5
```

Any one have seen similar problem?
Also, I'm not so sure that this way is giving me the very first data row!

Comment: Please keep in mind that in the results, I m getting the right columns names

Comment: Use the Range parameter as shown in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42677924/download-subset-of-file-from-s3-using-boto3

Comment: Guessing you should store `response['Body'].iter_lines()` in a local variable one time, and then call `__next__()` (or otherwise iterate) on that local variable as needed.

Answer (score 0):

Reading two lines of data may not include enough data to read the first two rows of a CSV file, since the CSV file might contain embedded newlines in a field.  The CSV reader module in Python can handle this quirk, so it's best to allow it to do all of the parsing of data.

So, rather than converting a line at a time and parsing it, you can pass the stream object that boto3 returns to a `TextIOWrapper` to convert the stream on demand, and let the CSV reader read as much data as it needs to process the file for you:

```python
import csv
import boto3
import io

s3 = boto3.client('s3')
resp = s3.get_object(Bucket=bucket, Key=key)
cr = csv.reader(io.TextIOWrapper(resp['Body'], encoding="utf-8"))
header = next(cr)
first_data_row = next(cr)

print(f"Header columns: {len(header)}")
print(f"First data row columns: {len(first_data_row)}")
```