# Split class 'bytes' into 50 MB byte chunks

Tags: python-3.x, multithreading, amazon-s3, bytestream, filesplitting

I am reading an object from S3 using boto3. I am creating class 'bytes' object from it.
It is around 520 MB file, I need to upload it to a new FTP server.

upload to FTP server uses multiupload session and can upload only 50 MB bute at max in one go.

How can I split this one big byte into multiple bytes or list of 50 MB bytes so that I can call multiupload session for each 50 MB byte.

```
s3_response_object=s3.get_object(Bucket='test', Key='prefix/file.test')
object_content = s3_response_object['Body'].read()
print(len(object_content))
```

Comment: That `read()` takes an optional option saying how much you want to read, if you want to read something less than all of the data, you can specify it there.  Also, you can specify a [byte range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42677924/download-subset-of-file-from-s3-using-boto3) to load part of an object.